# getBoundingClientRect() does not work in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dom

Every example I am seeing about positioning a tooltip manually involves getting client boundaries, which you would get through getBoundingClientRect() on the element.

I have a lightning component with this div in it:

`<div aura:id="testDiv">blahblahblahblahblah</div>`

That is wrapped in nothing but the `<aura:component>`.

So in my controller I do:

`component.find('testDiv').getElement().getBoundingClientRect();` and get:
[image]

So then I found information on possibly having to set functions back in the context of window, so tried doing various things like this:

```
var testElement = component.find('testDiv').getElement();

    /*var elementBoundaries = {
        boundingRect: testElement.getBoundingClientRect.bind(window)
    };
```

and calling elementBoundaries.boundingRect, but get a 'cannot read property 'apply' of undefined error.

I am looking at an example that is doing this:

```
var popoverEl = component.find('popover').getElement();
    var popoverBoundingBox = popoverEl.getBoundingClientRect();
    var popoverWidth = Math.ceil(popoverBoundingBox.width);
    var popoverHeight = popoverBoundingBox.height;
```

So why is it that I am entirely unable to use getBoundingClientRect???? Trying to get the dang coordinates for this element is honestly getting ridiculous. I am out of ideas and options...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're possibly overthinking it. Debugging from a FilteringProxyHandler will result in the illegal invocation error you're seeing, but simply accessing the parameters normally shouldn't cause an error:

```
var rect = component.find("testDiv").getElement().getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(rect.top);
console.log(rect.left);
...
```

Comment: Holy moly that does work. Good to know that I need to just actually drill down into the objects when they throw illegal invocation exceptions when dealing with lightning components. I didn't even bother because it looked like the method was failing. I shall keep that in mind. Thanks a ton!